# psql: how to exit with error if query returns 'False'?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I'm using `psql` to check if a table exists in a given database. The command below works fine to return `t` for True or `f` for False:

```sh
psql -U $user -d $db -t -c "SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename='$wanted');"
```

When the table doesn't exist, I get '`f`'.

Instead, I would like `psql` to exit with a non-zero exit status if the query returned False.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
psql -U $user -d $db -t -c "select * from '$wanted' limit 1"
echo $?
```

If the table does not exist the exit code is 1.

Comment: That works. I ended up just doing directly the query I wanted as if it were the right database, and redirecting stderr to /dev/null.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I try to avoid provoking errors from SQL queries. Rather, I aim to work with the results they return and make sense of them.

That said, you could (quite hacky approach!) provoke a division by zero:

```sql
SELECT (1 / (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename='$wanted'))::int::boolean;
```

If a table with the desired name is not existing, the query will fail with `ERROR: division by zero`. If a table with the desired name is existing, the query will return `true`.